# Mask URL rewrite in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a wordpress website in project and I want to mask the URL of all the pages so that when accessing them:

https://myweb.com/survey/page1

https://myweb.com/survey/page2

....

is displayed as:

https://myweb.com/survey/portal

I have this on .htaccess but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /survey/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /survey/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^survey/?$ /survey/portal/
```

Thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice efforts first of all, could you please try following; written based on your shown samples. Please clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Also please your .htaccess file just one level above `survey` folder.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /survey/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/portal [R=301]
RewriteRule ^ survey/index.php [L]
```

Comment: @Loco, Hello, could you please do let me know if my answer has helped you? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is a common misconception that rewrite rules make ugly URLs pretty; it is more correct to say that **they make externally pretty URLs internally ugly**.

That's because when the browser sends a request *to* the web server, the web server can decide what *response* to serve, but it can't change what the browser sent - that's already happened.

So if you type `https://myweb.com/survey/portal` into a web browser, the URL sent to the server at `myweb.com` will be `/survey/portal`. Your rewrite rules decide what to do when receiving that URL, so your rule might look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/portal$ survey/index.php
```

On the left is the URL the browser sent; on the right is what to serve. But notice that it wouldn't make sense to write this:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/portal$ survey/page1.php
RewriteRule ^survey/portal$ survey/page2.php
RewriteRule ^survey/portal$ survey/page3.php
```

These all match the same URL, and that URL is all we have to go on, so **there is no way to map one URL to multiple pages** using this mechanism. You would need something somewhere else to know which page of the survey the user is on.

You can of course do the opposite - match multiple URLs in the browser to the same resource internally:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/page1$ survey/index.php
RewriteRule ^survey/page2$ survey/index.php
RewriteRule ^survey/page3$ survey/index.php
```

Or you can map them to slightly different resources:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/page1$ survey/index.php?page=1
RewriteRule ^survey/page2$ survey/index.php?page=2
RewriteRule ^survey/page3$ survey/index.php?page=3
```

And you can use patterns and placeholders to avoid having to list out all the possibilities, so that last example can be shortened to:

```
RewriteRule ^survey/page([1-3])$ survey/index.php?page=$1
```